# Can React components inside node modules contain react-router

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, node-modules, package.json

I'm creating a **Node Package** using React. I have to use **react router** for the component. Is it possible to use react router inside the component because i haven't seen react router inside any other common components.

If it's not possible how i can make the routing mechanism inside the component. Do i need to break it to **separate individual components** which will handle the routing through main project.

**Please help me to figure out a solution for this.**

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by using `<Switch></Switch>` in `react-router-dom`. You can use it inside any component for in-page navigation.

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router';

class MyComponent extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path="/" component={Section1}/>
        <Route path="/section-2" component={Section2}/>
        <Route path="/section-3" component={Section3}/>
      </Switch>
    )
  }
}

export default MyComponent;
```